# How can the popoverview in the iPad master-detail split view (portrait) background be made translucent in iOS7?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller, translucency

I have a iPad master/detail storyboard made up for iOS5/6 where the popoverview that appears in landscape mode had a dark grey translucent background Like this. After the last cell in the tableview on the master popover controller, the detail view underneath is showing through the dark grey background.

[image: iOS6]

Rendering in iOS7 is corrupted, just shows 2 grey bars on either side and a big hole in the middle.

[image]

If I set the View's background colour like this

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.5];
```

I get a transparent grey colour but the ugly opaque grey bars are still there instead of the feathered edges that were there in iOS6.

[image]

Ideally it would look great as the new blurred out translucency like the iOS7 translucent navigation bar etc.

Also, the png files used for the cell backgrounds have transparency in iOS6..

[image]

..but have ugly white background with 1px black border in iOS7. This is with the Image, the Cell, The Cell's content and the TableView all with background colour set to 'clear colour' in IB. Help!!

[image]